# Thousand Plate World: Effects

Tags: planets, geology, tectonics

I have found this idea on a discussion on /r/worldbuilding. Anyway, the premise is as follows:

- The planet is earth-like in terms of size and mass.
- The planet has a very large amount of small, active, mobile tectonic plates (several hundred to several thousand).

My question here is:

- What are the implications of the high plate number on the appearance, geology and surface conditions of the planet?

Comment: I don't really understand why this is on hold. This questions seems answerable if one includes their resources and any supporting evidence.

Comment: It's too broad because "what are the implications..." questions are broad by definition. Implications for what? Continent building? Mountain raising? Planetquakes? Volcanism? Climate? Tectonic shift? The basic question is awesome -- and is a perfect fit for a discussion forum like CBB or Reddit -- but for SE needs to be focused much more sharply.

Comment: MedwedianPresident -- please edit your question and focus on one problem only! (You can certainly ask a different query related to the same topic later!) For now, even I'd say this question should remain closed.

Comment: You should separate this onto seperate questions each focused on a Downey sourdough subject. What the climates would be like on each micro plate for example